# Can not add items to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems at adding items to a list, following is my code:

```
using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
{
    Question Q = new Question();
    Q.Text = "O triunfo do FC Porto frente ao Benfica arrumou de vez as contas do título?";
    Q.Answer.Add ="Sim, o FC Porto vai ser campeão.");


    Q.Answer.Add('Sim, o FC Porto vai ser campeão');
    Q.Answer.Add("Não, o Benfica ainda tem uma palavra a dizer.");
    Q.Answer.Add("Não, o Sporting ainda vai ser campeão.");
    Q.Answer.Add("Não ligo a futebol.");
    poolDbContext.Questions.Add(Q);
    poolDbContext.Answers.Add(Q);
    var count = poolDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

And here is my .Models.Questions:

```
public class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answer { get; set; }

}
```

I'd like it to receive on the Models.Question the questions and the 4 answers for that questions.
Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

**Edit:**

Here is the `Answer`-class:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 

namespace PoolManager.Models 
{ 
    public class Answer 
    { 
        public string Questions { get; set; } 
        public string Answers { get; set; } 
        public string Results { get; set; } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your `Answer` property is `List<Answer>` - you need to add an instance of `Answer` to it - `Q.Answer.Add(new Answer{ ..... });`

Comment: I may not be familiar enough with `C#`, but in `poolDbContext.Answers.Add(Answer == "Não, o Benfica ainda tem uma palavra a dizer.");` for example, the "==" seems pretty strange, isn't that an expression ?

Comment: Show your `Answer` class

Comment: @SlavenHvar using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace PoolManager.Models
{
     public class Answer
    {
        public string Questions { get; set; }
        public string Answers { get; set; }
        public string Results { get; set; }

    }
}

Comment: @dorinmunteanu and the texts like "Sim, o FC Porto vai ser campeão" is supposed to go in which property of Answer class?

Comment: Where are your Primary Key-Columns?

Comment: Please don't give things that are different the same name. `public List<Answer> Answer` (just make it plural)  `public string AnswerText { get; set; } `

Comment: Your Question class has an Answers list . It seems a bit redundant for the Answer class to have a Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something like

```
        Q.Answer.Add(new Answer("Sim, o FC Porto vai ser campeão"));
```

in this case Answer needs to have a Constructor with a string or you make Answer a string. also for strings use " " and not ' ' //these are for chars

edit:
your answer class should look sth like this:

```
public class Answer
{
    public string Questions { get; set; }
    public string Answers { get; set; }
    public string Results { get; set; }

    public Answer(string text)
    {
         Answers = text;
    }

    public Answer(string question, string answer, string results)
    {
         Questions = question;
         Answers = answer;
         Results = results;
    }
}
```

Comment: or Answer could have a public property, let's call it `Text` and you can use property initialization like this : `new Answer { Text = "Sim, o FC ..." }`

Comment: "Answer" does not contain constructor that takes 1 arguments, this is the message that im getting

Comment: @dorinmunteanu So what's keeping you from simply _adding_ such a constructor? It's your own code, no?

Answer (score 0):

initialize your Answer list in constructor

```
public class Question
{
    public string Text {get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers {get; set; } 


     public Question(){
     Answers=new List<Answer>();
    }
}
```

Add New Items like this

Answers.Add(new Answer{propert1=value1, property2=value2});

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
Q.Answer.Add('Sim, o FC Porto vai ser campeão');
```

...the code thinks you are trying to add an answer, but you are actually giving it a string literal.

If an answer *is* a string, I suggest making this change:

```
public class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<string> Answer { get; set; }  //<-- just store strings
}
```

If an answer is actually more complicated, but can be initialized from a string, you can do this:

```
Q.Answer.Add(new Answer("Sim, o FC Porto vai ser campeão"));
```

Or if you want to be particularly clever you can set up an implicit conversion:

```
public class Answer 
{ 
    public string Answers { get; set; } 

    static public implicit operator Answer(string input)
    {
        var a = new Answer();
        a.Answers = input;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Once you add the implicit conversion operator, you can now use this again:

```
Q.Answer.Add("Sim, o FC Porto vai ser campeão");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I managed to make it alone, the right way to do it is

```
        using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
        {
            if (poolDbContext.Questions.Count() == 0)
            {
                Question Q = new Question();

                Q.Text = "O triunfo do FC Porto frente ao Benfica arrumou de vez as contas do título?";

                Q.Answers.Add(new Answer { Answers = "Sim, o FC Porto vai ser campeão." });
                Q.Answers.Add(new Answer { Answers = "Não, o Benfica ainda tem uma palavra a dizer." });
                Q.Answers.Add(new Answer { Answers = "Não, o Sporting ainda vai ser campeão." });
               Q.Answers.Add(new Answer { Answers = "Não ligo a futebol." });
                poolDbContext.Questions.Add(Q);
                var count = poolDbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return View();
```